Attributes on Python flag enums
I was very happy to learn Enum types can effectively carry named attributes:
from enum import Enum

class ActivityType(Enum):
    NEXT = 0, "N"
    JOIN = 3, "J"
    DIVIDE_REAR = 1, "DR"
    DIVIDE_FRONT = 2, "DF"

    def __init__(self, xml_code, label):
        self.xml_code = xml_code
        self.label = label

assert ActivityType.JOIN.label == "J"
assert ActivityType.DIVIDE_FRONT.xml_code == 2

How can I do something similar for Flag enums? Here, something can have a combination of PowerTypes, and the string representation has a code for each one which are combined in a specific order:
class PowerType(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    AC_OVERHEAD = auto()
    DC_3RAIL = auto()
    DIESEL = auto()

    def xml_code(self):
        powertype_subcode = {
            PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD: "O",
            PowerType.DC_3RAIL: "3",
            PowerType.DIESEL: "D",
        }
        return "".join(sc for pt, sc in powertype_subcode.items() if pt & self)

assert (PowerType.DIESEL | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code() == "3D"
assert (PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code() == "O3"

I'd like to do something like this and eliminate that powertype_subcode dict:
class PowerType(Flag):
    NONE = 0, ""
    AC_OVERHEAD = auto(), "O"
    DC_3RAIL = auto(), "3"
    DIESEL = auto(), "D"

    def __init__(self, flag, xml_code):
        self.flag = flag
        self._xml_subcode = xml_code

    def xml_code(self):
        return "".join(pt._xml_subcode for pt in PowerType if pt & self)

However this causes problems with auto() and _generate_next_value_ and if I work around that, it then finds it can't do bitwise operations on tuple values.

Using @JackDeeth's answer as a basis, changing xml_code to a property, and saving _xml_subcode when absent, solves the problem:
from enum import Flag, auto

class PowerType(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    AC_OVERHEAD = auto(), "O"
    DC_3RAIL = auto(), "3"
    DIESEL = auto(), "D"
    #
    def __new__(cls, flag, xml_code = ""):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = flag
        obj._xml_subcode = xml_code
        return obj
    #
    @property
    def xml_code(self):
        code = getattr(self, '_xml_subcode', None)
        if code is None:
            code = "".join(pt._xml_subcode for pt in self)
            self._xml_subcode = code
        return code

# Assertions still pass (after removing parenthesis from xml_code)
assert (PowerType.DIESEL | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code == "3D"
assert (PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code == "O3"
assert (PowerType.DIESEL | PowerType.DC_3RAIL)._xml_subcode == "3D"
assert (PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD | PowerType.DC_3RAIL)._xml_subcode == "O3"

Note also that flags are themselves iterable, so instead of for pt in PowerType I'm using for pt in self.

Disclosure:  I am the author of the Python stdlib Enum, the enum34 backport, and the Advanced Enumeration (aenum)  library.

Oh thanks, this is much better!

A solution is to set the ._value_ attribute to just the flag value (0, 1, 2, 4...), which can only be done in __new__. The other data gets stored as attributes:
class PowerType(Flag):
    NONE = 0
    AC_OVERHEAD = auto(), "O"
    DC_3RAIL = auto(), "3"
    DIESEL = auto(), "D"

    def __new__(cls, flag, xml_code = ""):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = flag
        obj._xml_subcode = xml_code
        return obj

    def xml_code(self):
        return "".join(pt._xml_subcode for pt in PowerType if pt & self)

# Assertions still pass
assert (PowerType.DIESEL | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code() == "3D"
assert (PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD | PowerType.DC_3RAIL).xml_code() == "O3"

A possible problem with attributes on flags is they exist for individual flags but not combined flags:
ac = PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD
acdc = PowerType.AC_OVERHEAD | PowerType.DC_3RAIL
ac._xml_subcode   # "O"
acdc._xml_subcode # AttributeError: 'PowerType' object has no attribute '_xml_subcode'

It's not a problem if you don't look up, or if you have a method which coalesces the attributes from the component flags as here.

(I discovered this solution while drafting the question - if there's any better approaches please let me know!)
